# Row Number to give same value when same partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to get the row number equal when the name is the same in the `SELECT` statement?

When I try with following code:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BENFNAME ORDER BY BENFNAME DESC, BENFNAME DESC) AS ROWNUM
    , BENFNAME, BENLNAME
    , REMID, BENENATIONALITY 
    , CUSBENRELATION
FROM  SEND    
WHERE REMID = 445231
```

[image]

I need MEHARUN with the same row number, i.e. if any same name exit it should be in same row number.

Expected results:

[image]

Comment: Use `DENSE_RANK()` instead.

Comment: Please do not use images for data, use table markdown as provided by the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dense Rank instead of Row Number,

```
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY BENFNAME ORDER BY BENFNAME DESC, BENFNAME DESC) AS ROWNUM
    , BENFNAME, BENLNAME
    , REMID, BENENATIONALITY 
    , CUSBENRELATION
FROM  SEND    
WHERE REMID = 445231
```